# Navigation Bar partially hidden only in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a Tab Bar Controller with Nav Controller. In this Nav Controller have a Navigation Bar.

The implementation it's very simple, there are not custom code. I do all with graphical interface in Xcode.

If I open the application in iOS4 it's perfect.

[image: NavigationBar in iOS4]

But If I open in iOS5 or iOS 5.0.1 ... It's partially hidden with status bar.

[image: NavigationBar in iOS5]

How I can fix it?

EDIT: This is my implementation in MainWindow.xib (sorry I need remove some names)

[image: Implementation]

Comment: do you use xib? Do is the navigation bar of a navigation controller? Is navigation bar created by you and added as a sub view?

Comment: I think why the guy down voted my answer with out an comment or a better answer

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem with an old project made by other devs who used the xib.
My solution is that you have to write some code:d if you did the drag and drop programing approach.
So:

In viewWillAppear move all your ui elements with 20 pixels down. 
I added tags in xib for each element and with a static int I keep tract of changes to be done only once.

```
static int oneTine = 0;
    if(!oneTine){
        for(int index = 1001; index<=1005; index++){
           UIView *currentView = [self.view viewWithTag:index];
            CGRect viewFrame = currentView.frame;
            viewFrame.origin.y -=20; 
            currentView.frame = viewFrame;
        }
     oneTine = 1;
    }
```

Comment: The code doesn't work. But I try other solution based in this: put tag 50 to Navigation Bar and write this in viewWillAppear: 
`UIView *currentView = [self.view viewWithTag:50];
CGRect viewFrame = currentView.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -=20; 
currentView.frame = viewFrame;`

And I do not usually make negative votes. I always appreciate the help ;)

Comment: did you modify the code? Because the code is working for tags from 1001 to 1005

Comment: Test to see if the view is keindof  UINavigationbar